# Connection refused when inserting

Tags: postgresql, etl

**Description:**

```
Machine 1: Linux, PostgreSQL 9.3, on local, 10.12.10.123
Machine 2: Linux, PostgreSQL 9.3, on cloud, 104.10.124.123
Configuration (on both):
+ postgresql.conf : listen_addresses ="*"
+ pg_hba.conf : accept "trust" for both 10.12.10.123, 104.10.124.123 
+ using postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc3.jar
```

I am using Talend tool to ETL data from machine 1 to machine 2:

```
Database on machine 1 - table A - 10,000 rows 
Database on machine 2 - table A - 0 rows
```

PSQL connection is OK. When running ETL, I am sure that client on machine 1 is connected to PG database on machine 2 , I tracked by query below

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

**Problem:**

I tested over 10 times, each of times when data is inserted about 2,000 rows (**2,000 records is commited into machine 2**) , with insert time about 3 minutes , I got errors:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.<init>(Jdbc3gConnection.java:24)
```

I would like to know how I can fix it.

Comment: How many connections are allowed? (`SHOW max_connections;`)  Can it be that a new run is started while the previous one is still running?

Comment: @dezso You'd get a different error in that case. Unnnh: I'm wondering if this is a Windows system with a low limit on max TCP/IP connections at the operating system level. It's weird that it connects, then fails later. Have you looked the PostgreSQL server error logs on both machines?

Comment: Space? Permissions?

Comment: @dezso: database max_connection = 512, with pg_stat_activity , I got six connections when running ETL.

Comment: @Vérace: data size is very small, about 60 MB, empty disk space ~ 9 GB.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I run my Talend Job on window to connect machine 2, It works fine. And log file in pg_log is empty.